# Properties of horizontal divisors on a fibered surface.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be an integral, regular, projective scheme of dimension $2$, flat over $\operatorname{Spec }\mathbb Z$. I have a couple of questions about horizontal and vertical divisors on $X$:

1. Is it always possible to find two horizontal divisors on $X$ with no intersection points? I'm tempted to say yes, but I'm not able to prove it formally.
2. Given an *irreducible horizontal* divisor $D$ is it always possible to find a *vertical* divisor $E$ linearly equivalent to $D$?

Many Thanks

Comment: I think over DVR, question 1 has an affirmative answer. Let $R$ be a DVR and consider $\mathscr{X} \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Let $D$ be a horizontal divisor, then $D$ as a set is finite. Liu Qing book Proposition 3.3.36(b) then says $D$ is contained in an affine open $U$. Then $Z=\mathscr{X}-U$ (as complement of an affine open) is a divisor that does not meet $D$. This $Z$ is of course horizontal.

Comment: Question 2 seems to be impossible. Suppose a horizontal divisor $D$ is linearly equivalent to a vertical one $E$. Consider another vertical divisor $E^\prime$ which is not in the same fibre as $E$. Then $(E,E^\prime)=0$, while $(D,E^\prime)$ can certainly be non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for the first question is yes, because horizontal divisors correspdoning to the closure of points in the generic fiber (see Liu). So if you pick different points, they will give you different closures. I think horizontal divisors and vertical divisors are almost never equivalent.

Comment: Your first answer is not correct. It's true that different points will have different closures, but the OP asked whether or not they have _no_ intersection points. It's perfectly possible for two horizontal divisors to intersect.

Comment: @Nefertiti: Yes, I think this is a good point. Perhaps I should assume they have no intersection on the finite part to begin with.

Comment: @Nefertiti: Do not hestiate if you have an answer for the first question. As you pointed out mine is not entirely correct.

Comment: Yes, using Liu book we can just say that two irreducible horizontal divisors don't have intersection points on the generic fiber.